# Are database queries for everyone in a user list too much?

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization

I am currently using MySQL and MyISAM.

I have a function of which returns an array of user IDs of either friends or users in general in my application, and when displaying them a foreach seemed best.

Now my issue is that I only have the IDs, so I would need to nest a database call to get each user's other info (i.e. name, avatar, other fields) based on the user ID in the loop.

I do not expect hundreds of thousands of users (mainly for hobby learning), although how should I do this one, such as the flexibility of placing code in a foreach for display, but not relying on ID arrays so I am out of luck to using a single query?

Any general structures or tips on what I can display the list appropriately with?

Is my amount of queries (1:1 per users in list) inappropriate? (although pages 0..n of users, 10 at a time make it seem not as bad I just realize.)

Comment: I *think* that you could do a OR statement in the where for each IDs that you need, although I'm not 100% sure if it's the best way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the IN() MySQL method, i.e.

```
SELECT username,email,etc FROM user_table WHERE userid IN (1,15,36,105)
```

That will return all rows where the userid matches those ID's. It gets less efficient the more ID's you add but the 10 or so you mention should be just fine.

Comment: Or you could do that too :) -> kicks @Bulk for having a better answer

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question when I gave my answer sorry

Comment: Thank you, this seems excellent compared to what I have been doing, from the other answers I am excited to learn JOINs to see if I can do it with those too. I love advice :)

Comment: @aaron: A JOIN would not be the best solution then? I think because I have profile data within the users table or whatnot I could not do that example. Edit: would storing users separate from profiles be better?

Comment: If you have the profile data you want in the same table as the userid's then neither the IN() or the JOIN is needed - you can simply request all the data at the same time.. or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @KennyR A JOIN would be the best solution *IF* you are pulling data from multiple tables.  The better part of the answer I was noting above was the WHERE userid IN (...) allowing you to select the ID's you want to pull

Comment: Don't forget to give out the checkmark if this is the answer you most like.  It's like an MMO, trying to get those points :)

Comment: @Bulk yes and no, the WHERE userid IN (-array of ids-), so the WHERE/IN portion will allow you to select just the records that match certain ID's

Comment: You guys :). I will accept this one, it'll fit nice with other code in the future that uses this format of IDs, other answers definitely inspired me to learn joins however.

Answer (score 1):

Why couldn't you just use a left join to get all the data in 1 shot?  It sounds like you are getting a list, but then you only need to get all of a single user's info.  Is that right?

Remember databases are about result SETS and while generally you can return just a single row if you need it, you almost never have to get a single row then go back for more info.

For instance a list of friends might be held in a text column on a user's entry.

Comment: The OP says this is "hobby learning".  In that case, learn it correctly from the start and follow meteor's advice, do a join or two so that all information is returned in a set.  This allows any kind of foreach coding you want.

Comment: @KenDowns (this is off topic) but what does OP mean? (I know you are referring to the question author but what does OP stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you expect to have a small database or large database, I would consider using the InnoDB engine rather than MyISAM.  It does have a little higher overhead for processing than MyISAM, however you get all the added benefits (as your hobby grows) including JOIN, which will allow you to pull in specific data from multiple tables:

```
SELECT u.`id`, p.`name`, p.`avatar`
  FROM `Users` AS u
  LEFT JOIN `Profiles` AS p USING `id`
```

Would return id from Users and name and avatar from Profiles (where id of both tables match)

There are numerous resources online talking about database normalization, you might enjoy: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/

Comment: myisam allows for joins. I do it all the time.

Comment: @meteorainer you are right, it is the foreign key constraints that it doesn't provide for.  I knew there was a reason I switched to InnoDB (along with transactions)

Comment: AH, ya I actually just learned that the other day about the FKs.  And what was odd was that I had written the key-making sql as calling FKs and got no errors.  It had just made regular ole' indexes.